# Nullstellensatz and field of definition

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k\subset\overline{k}$ be a field and its algebraic closure. We've learned the nullstellensatz, i.e. for an ideal $I$ of $k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$, the radical of $I$ is equal to the set of polynomials in $k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ that vanish on all solution for $I$ in ${\overline{k}}^{n}$.

Then we set $k=\overline{k}$ and saw that NSZ implies that the set of algebraic subsets of ${\overline{k}}^{n}$ corresponds bijectively with the set of radical ideals of $\overline{k}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$.

But I don't want to set $k=\overline{k}$. I think that we get that the set of radical ideals of $k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ corresponds bijectively with the set of algebraic subsets of ${\overline{k}}^{n}$ that arise from ideals of $k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$.

Am I correct about this?

So am I also correct the the maximal ideals of $k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ correspond to the minimal subsets from the set of nonempty algebraic subsets of ${\overline{k}}^{n}$ that arise from ideals of $k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. If you want to do algebraic geometry over non-algebraically-closed fields, there are better gadgets to use which you will probably learn about a little further in to your algebraic geometry career.

Comment: @KReiser: Thank you. Can you give me some buzzwords in relation to these gadgets?

Comment: Schemes. ${}{}{}$

Comment: @Object Not sure if that is your question, but note that the same correspondence that we have in the algebraically closed case stops being bijective in general. Two distinct points in $\overline{k}^n$ might correspond to the same maximal ideal of $k[x_1,...,x_n]$. For example, take $n=1$ and $k=\mathbb{R}$. The points $i$ and $-i$ are the roots of exactly the same polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[x]$, the ones that belong to the maximal ideal $(x^2+1)$.

Comment: @Mark: In my question, I am only considering algebraic sets that can be defined over the smaller field $k$ ($\mathbb{R}$ in your case). An I asked if the minimal among these (excluding the empty set) correspond to the maximal ideals of $k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$.

Comment: @Mark: And whether this correspondence in bijective.

Comment: @KReiser: In the classical setting, I can work over the algebraic closure of $k$, and then use the action of $\text{Gal}(\overline{k}/k)$ (say $k$ is perfect) on points or absolutely irreducible components to study what happens over $\overline{k}$. For example, an orbit of this action of corresponds to a $k$-irreducible component. Is this kind of reasoning useful with schemes too? Is it still useful, with schemes, to go to the algebraic closure and come back, or does this idea become not-so-useful?

Comment: You can still do that with schemes - they package all the data together in a nice way that makes that and many other things you'd like to do easier.

Comment: Can't wait to learn about schemes.